Model.save_pretrained is not saving .bin files
args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir=""output_bert_training2"",
    num_train_epochs=2,
    per_device_train_batch_size=8,
       weight_decay=0.01,
   evaluation_strategy=""epoch"",
   save_strategy=""epoch"",
    load_best_model_at_end=True,
    metric_for_best_model=""eval_loss"",

)
trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=args,
    train_dataset=train_dataset,
    eval_dataset=val_dataset,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
     callbacks=[EarlyStoppingCallback(early_stopping_patience=3)],
)
trainer.train()
trainer.save_model('CustomModel_4000_2')

Attempted to save the model using trainer.save_model(model_path)
Expected that upon saving the model using trainer.save_model(model_path), all necessary files including model.bin would be saved.
Observed that only the files training_args.bin, model.safetensors, and config.json were saved, while model.bin was not included.

model.safetensors is the binary of your model, model.bin is not used on new versions of transformers but safer format .safetensors
